# push empty array as value of an array key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to push a new array as the value of a parent array key.

this is my array.

```
asd[
[hey],
[hi]

]
```

i would like to return.

```
asd[
[hey]=>[],
[hi]
]
```

i do:

```
var asd = new Array();
asd.push(hey);
asd.push(hi);
asd[hey].push(new Array());

so obviously is not ok my code
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: It would then be an `Array` with a `hey` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `new Array();` you should just write `[]`. You can create a nested array like this

```
myarray =
[
    "hey",
    "hi",
    [
        "foo"
    ]
]
```

Remember that when you push things into an array, it's given a numerical index. Instead of `asd[hey]` write `asd[0]` since `hey` would have been inserted as the first item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function myArray(){this.push = function(key){ eval("this." + key + " = []");};}

//example
test = new myArray();

//create a few keys
test.push('hey');
test.push('hi');

//add a value to 'hey' key
test['hey'].push('hey value');

// => hey value
alert( test['hey'] );
```

Take notice that in this example `test` is not an `array` but a `myArray` instance.

---

If you already have an array an want the values to keys:

```
function transform(ary){
    result= []; 
    for(var i=0; i< ary.length; i++){result[ary[i]] = [];}
    return result;
}

//say you have this array
test = ['hey','hi'];

//convert every value on a key so you have 'ary[key] = []'
test = transform(test);

//now you can push whatever
test['hey'].push('hey value');

// => hey value
alert( test['hey'] );
```

In this case `test` remains an `array`.